# MacMini freezes with USB3 device attached OSX

Tags: osx-mavericks

My 2013 MacMini will freeze up if I have my WD USB3 disk attached upon boot.  If I detach the drive boot then reattach its fine.  Anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The MacMini is most likely trying to boot from the WD disk thinking it is a bootable device. You can simple go into System Preferences > Startup Disk and select your Internet boot drive (HDD). Restart and test to see if you can leave your external drive connected on reboot.